# targeting 'category' in css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My Wordpress site shows the post-title and category over-top the featured image.

I want to get the text to be `#ffffff` (white). I successfully targeted both in my css, but the 'category' doesn't change colour like the post-title did.

css

```
.title-styling {
  width: 85%;
  position: relative;
}

.title-styling h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font: 700 60px/50px "Open Sans";
}

.title-styling h2 {
  color: #fff !important;
  font: 500 15px/10px "Open Sans";
}
```

html

```
 <div class="box-title">
     <div class="title-styling">
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
        <h2 class="box-meta"><?php the_category(', '); ?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

The text size and text-colour changed correctly for `.title-styling h1 {`
but only the text size changed for `.title-styling h2 {` (I tried with and without `!important`)

Comment: We're gonna need a demo (or a link) to see this not working...but it's likely that you have some other rule overiding this...probably the `box-meta` class.

Comment: Yeah, use "_.box-title h2.box-meta_" or something. Basically with CSS you have to keep getting more specific until the rule applies.

Comment: Does the PHP variable within the `<h2>` generate plain text or HTML? If the latter then you may have some other styles applied to those tags overriding your styles for the `<h2>` element.

Comment: I figured the !important would override any pre-determined attributes. There's a lot of included files that may affect this so I don't know what all to include.

Comment: I did manage to fix it, apparently it created a link not plain text, even though not wrapped in an href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do one of the following:-

Remove class="box-meta" from the h2 tag

OR

Include a css class "box-meta" in your css file

Comment: A mix of what you suggested seemed to work, You don't by chance know what 'box-meta' in that context means. It's from the parent file so I don't know why they used it

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that the problem is the `<h2>` tag having a "More specific" class, try changing your CSS like this:

```
.title-styling > h2.box-meta {
    color: #fff;
    font: 500 15px/10px "Open Sans";
}
```

Comment: I managed to target it, its weird that I was able to target the text size through the css I had, but I changed it to '.title-styling a {' and that targeted the text also (and was able to change the colour)